# Changing Objective-C SDK settings from the application using it

Tags: objective-c, sdk

I have a question regarding modifying SDK settings from the application using it.

I have a custom SDK which prints to a log when doing certain things. I want users of this SDK to be able to turn logging on/off. I use NSLog as my logger.

I have tried setting a preprocessor macro for this, as explained numerous times here in stackoverflow by doing something like:

```
#ifdef SHOWLOG
#   define SLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define SLog(...)

#endif
```

And then expecting the user to set a compile flag called "-DSHOWLOG"

This does not work since the person who is using the SDK will have a compiled version of the SDK.

What other ways are there are there of changing configurations of SDK from the application that uses it? 
Are environment variables a good option?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, so I'll guess and offer this answer in the hope it helps:

1. Inside your SDK create your settings which you query to control how your SDK behaves. These settings can be stored in a shared/singleton object, behind a functional (i.e. C functions) API, or even just SDK (not publicly documented) global variables.
2. Provide a public API which alters the values of these settings.

So in the situation mentioned in the question you need an SDK-internal "show log" setting and a public API to set it.

HTH